# Merging three queries that use 1:* relationships into one query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

Lets say i have four tables i want to read from:

**customer**

```
customer_id,    customer_name
1               Joe Bolggs
```

**customer_orders**

```
customer_id, order_no
----------------------------
1       1
1       2
1       3
```

**customer_addresses**

```
customer_id address
----------------------------
1       11 waterfall road
1       23 The broadway
```

**customer_tel_no**

```
customer_id number
----------------------------
1       523423423432
1       234342342343
```

The customer information shown above (for the customer with id=1) is to be stored in a Java object as shown below

```
public class Customer{

    String customer_id;
    String customerName;
    ArrayList<String> customerOrders;
    ArrayList<String> customerAddress;
    ArrayList<String> customerTelephoneNumbers;
}
```

The only way i can think of to get the above information is by using three queries. The reason is that there is a 1:* relationship between the customer table and each of the other tables. To get the data i am doing something like this:

```
Customer customer = new Customer()

String customerSQL = "Select * from customer where customer_id = ?";
statement = getConnection().prepareStatement(contactsQuery);
statement.setString(1,1);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(); 

while (resultSet.next()){
    customer.customer_id = resultSet.get(1);    //No getters/setters in this example
    customer.customerName = resultSet.get(2);
}

String customerOrdersSQL = "Select * from customer_orders where customer_id = ?";
statement = getConnection().prepareStatement(customerOrdersSQL); 
statement.setString(1,1);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(); 

customer.customerOrders = new ArrayList();
while (resultSet.next()){
    customer.customerOrders.add(resultSet.getString(2);  // all the order numbers
}


String customerAddressesSQL = "Select * from customer_addresses where customer_id = ?";
statement = getConnection().prepareStatement(customerAddressesSQL ); 
statement.setString(1,1);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(); 

customer.customerAddresses = new ArrayList();
while (resultSet.next()){
    customer.customerAddresses.add(resultSet.getString(2);  // all the addresses
}


String customerTelSQL = "Select * from customer_tel_no where customer_id = ?";
statement = getConnection().prepareStatement(customerTelSQL); 
statement.setString(1,1);
resultSet = statement.executeQuery(); 

customer.customerTelephoneNumbers = new ArrayList();
while (resultSet.next()){
    customer.customerTelephoneNumbers.add(resultSet.getString(2);  // all the order numbers
}
```

The problem with the above is that i am making three calls to the database. Is there a way i can merge the above into a single query please?

I cant see how a join would work because for example, a join between customer and customer_orders will return a customer row for each row in customer_orders. Is there anyway i can merge the above three queries into one?

Comment: Ziggy:  You wrote "the problem ... is that i am making three calls to the database".  Why is that a problem?  If you're worried about the verbosity of your code, use an ORM framework (as suggested by @enno).  If you're worried about the long term maintenance, also use an ORM framework.  If you're worried about a _potential_ performance problem, wait until you see an actual performance problem, then refactor (anticipating performance problems can lead to unnecessary complexity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think that something like this would work:

```
SELECT c.customer_id, c.customer_name, o.order_no, a.address, t.number
FROM customer c LEFT JOIN customer_orders o ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
LEFT JOIN customer_addresses a ON c.customer_id = a.customer_id
LEFT JOIN customer_tel_no t ON c.customer_id = t.customer_id
WHERE c.customer_id = ?
```

Then, in your code, after you execute the query:

```
while (resultSet.next())
{
    customer.customerOrders.add(resultSet.getString(3));
    customer.customerAddresses.add(resultSet.getString(4));
    customer.customerTelephoneNumbers.add(resultSet.getString(5));
}
```

Of course, this does not take into account the fact that you will have null values along the way, so I'd advise checking for nulls to make sure that you aren't adding a lot of junk to your array lists. Still, that's probably a lot less costly than 3 separate queries.

Comment: I did try this but the problem is that each row in the parent table is duplicated for each of the rows in the child tables. Is that not avoidable?

Comment: so then just omit those columns from your query. To be clear, you will still need at least 2 queries: one to populate your customer "header" information and then one to populate the related data.

Comment: What i mean is for example, customer_name is only required in the first iteration of the result but it will exist in all iterations (if that makes sense) so the column cannot be omitted.

Comment: and what I mean is that you'll need to use 2 queries: your first query will be to the customers table and will get the customer_id and customer_name. You use that query to populate the relevant fields on your object. Then you can execute the query I suggested to fill in the related data (orders, addresses, phone numbers). You do not need to include the two customer fields in that second query.

Comment: be mindful of the fact that because orders, addresses, and phone numbers are not related to each other you will have null values along the way. For example, if you have a customer with 3 orders, 2 addresses, and 1 phone number, the query I suggested above will return 6 rows. 3 rows will have order data w/ null address and telephone, 2 rows will have address data with null order and telephone, and 1 row will have telephone data with null order and address.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing prevents you from iterating and processing the joined result into your customer object. If your application is complex enough, you could look into ORM frameworks which would do that for you under the covers. If you are working with JavaEE, have a look at JPA.

Comment: @ziggy yeah why not. You could do that by adding ORDER BY customer_id

Comment: Sorry i accidentally deleted the question i asked if i should store the id while iterating the results. :(

Comment: @ziggy If you are looking to extract all customers (for example) from the table, then yeah, iterate through the joined & ordered result set while doing 1) create customer object with the id, 2) keep adding phone/address etc. to that customer object if the id match, 3) if the id changes, store the customer object to your list, create a new customer object for the new id -> keep doing until you exhausted the result set

Answer (score 0):

use this query and reduce the number of call. And, in while loop process on data.

**select customer.customer_id,customer.customer_name,order_no,address,number**

**from customer,customer_orders,customer_addresses,customer_tel_no**

**where customer.customer_id = customer_orders.customer_id
AND
customer.customer_id = customer_addresses.customer_id
AND
customer.customer_id = customer_tel_no.customer_id**

Comment: You can select your code (while editing the answer) and hit the `{}` button. It will indent your code 4 columns to the right, so it will be visible as code.